# How to change the x-axis from normal numbers to date and time format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am generating a gaussian curve for one day with the peak occurring at a value that is inputted by the user. I am taking the frequency as 1 min, so in total in a day we will have 1440 mins.

I wrote a code that plots the graph for me. But for generating the graph I am using `np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)`.

Now, instead of the values from 0 to 1440 being on the x-axis, I want the date and the time to be present. I do have a pandas series of date and time as: `2018-01-01 00:00:00, 2018-01-01 00:01:00, 2018-01-01 00:02:00` and so on. But when I try to plot it, it takes on forever for it to plot and it gets stuck. Any idea as to how can I do this?

The peak value must occur at `2018-01-01 14:00:00` (that is why I gave my `mu` as 840)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import pandas as pd

date = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-01 23:59:59',freq='1min').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').tolist()
date = pd.Series(date)

mu = 840
def bell_curve(area, peak, base):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)
    sigma = area/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*peak)
    pdf_value = area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
    plt.plot(x, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))
    plt.show()
    return pdf_value

peak = int(input('Enter the peak value:'))
area = int(input('Enter the area value:'))
base = int(input('Enter the base value:'))

pdf = bell_curve(area, peak, base)
```

When I run this code, and give `peak, area, base` values as 1000, 700000, 300 respectively, I get a graph as follows:

[image]

We can see that in the x-axis there are values from 0 to 1440. Now, I tried to replace them with the values in `date` as `plt.plot(x, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))` with `plt.plot(date, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))`, and a dialog box opens and it takes on forever for it to plot and it gets stuck.

How can I achieve this and also how can I make sure that the peak value occurs at `2018-01-01 14:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are passing strings of date time values to matplotlib which doesn't know how to handle it. You need to pass the datetime objects or floats for your x-axis. Once you do this then you will want to adjust your figure size and/or use an axis formatter so you can see all the times at the interval you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import pandas as pd


date = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-01 23:59:59',freq='1min').tolist()
#date should be a list of date time objects. Don't use strftime to get strings.

mu = 840
def bell_curve(area, peak, base, dates):
    x = np.linspace(0, 1440, 1440)
    sigma = area/(math.sqrt(2*math.pi)*peak)
    pdf_value = area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
    plt.plot(dates, area*(stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)))
    plt.show()
    return pdf_value

peak = 1000
area = 700000
base = 300


pdf = bell_curve(area, peak, base,date)
```

[image]